# why i get circular import error in only one way?

Tags: python

#app.py

```
print('ran')
from model import func2
print('Imported')
def func1():
    pass
print('func defined')
func2()
```

#model.py

```
def func2():
    pass
from app import func1
func1()
```

### output

python app.py

```
ran
ran
Imported
func defined
Imported
func defined
```

python model.py

```
ran
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AFAM RK/PycharmProjects/deepdive/test/model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import func1
  File "C:\Users\AFAM RK\PycharmProjects\deepdive\test\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from model import func2
  File "C:\Users\AFAM RK\PycharmProjects\deepdive\test\model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import func1
ImportError: cannot import name 'func1' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\AFAM RK\PycharmProjects\deepdive\test\app.py)
```

app.py run without any error, but while running model.py i get circular import error.

why its happening?

why its not raise error while running app.py?

Answer (score 1):

If you run *python app.py* the interpeter

- prints *ran* (line 1)
- on line 2 it sees the *import* statement and starts reading *model.py*
- in *model.py* it sees first the definition of *func2* and saves its information for later usage.
- on the third line of model.py it sees the import statement and jumps back to *app.py*
- there it prints *ran* once more
- on the second line it sees (again) the import statement but remembers that this was already imported (python imports a module only once).
- now it executes the rest of *app.py* and therefore printing *imported* and *func defined* (still as part of the import that happened in *model.py* (print a string at the very end of *model.py* and you see that this string is printed after *func defined*)
- now the import of *model.py* is over and it continues running the remaining code of *app.py* resulting in printing *imported* and *func defined* again.

Now if you run *python model.py* the interpreter

- first sees the definition of *func2* and saves its information for later usage
- on the third line it sees the import statement and jumps to *app.py*
- there first *ran* is printed
- on the second line it sees the import statement and jumps back to *model.py*
- there again (after redefining func2) on the third line remembers, that this import was already done and jumps to line 4 but does not find *func1*. Now the error is reported.

Comment: while running model.py it first sees the definition of func2 and saves its information for later usage,on the third line it sees the import statement and jumps to app.py,on the second line it sees the import statement and jumps back to model.py.
but  why its need to jumps back to model.py ?The func2 is already defined at this point, also sys.modules contain model